# Can we pass a TLH property function to a lambda function?

Tags: visual-c++, lambda, com

When you have a COM API call, eg:

```
THROW_IF_FAIL(pCongregation->get_Name(&bstrValue));
rArchive << CString(bstrValue);
```

In the TLH file the above is defined as:

```
  virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_Name (
    /*[out,retval]*/ BSTR * pRetVal ) = 0;
```

I have several of these properties. I could like to write a lambda function, eg:

```
auto WriteStringPropertyToArchive = [&pCongregation, &rArchive](get_xxx)
{
    BSTR str{};
    THROW_IF_VALUE(pCongregation->get_xxx(&str));
    rArchive << CString(str);
};
```

And then call it like:

```
WriteStringPrpertyToArchive(get_Name);
WriteStringPrpertyToArchive(get_LocationMap);
```

At the moment I am using long hand:

```
THROW_IF_FAIL(pCongregation->get_Name(&bstrValue));
rArchive << CString(bstrValue);

THROW_IF_FAIL(pCongregation->get_LocationMap(&bstrValue));
rArchive << CString(bstrValue);
```

Is this possible with lambda function?

---

I am trying:

```
auto WriteStringPropertyToArchive = [&pCongregation, &rArchive](HRESULT(__stdcall MSAToolsLibrary::ICongregationPtr::*method)(BSTR*))
    {
        BSTR str{};
        (pCongregation->*method)(&str);
        rArchive << CString(str);
    };
```

But it flags issue:

[image]

Comment: `WriteStringPrpertyToArchive(&InterfaceType::get_Name)` can be made to work (where `InterfaceType` is the type of `*pCongregation`, the interface you are calling the method on). `WriteStringPrpertyToArchive(get_Name)` can only be made to work with a macro.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So a macro is better for this issue rather than a lambda function?

Comment: That's subjective. I personally wouldn't use a macro just to save typing a few characters, but to each their own. With a macro, you would be able to achieve your preferred syntax. With a lambda, you can have a slightly more verbose syntax.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ok. But with the lambda, how do I define the parameter? InterfaceType::Fnc() or something. I understand passing I the address of the function but I am not sure on definition of the lambda parameter.

Comment: `HRESULT (__stdcall InterfaceType::*method)(BSTR*)` . Then you call it as `(pCongregation->*method)(&str)`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ah, if I set the parameter as `ICongregation` it is OK.  Not `ICongregationPtr`.

Comment: Like I said, `InterfaceType` would be the type of `*pCongregation`, not the type of `pCongregation`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It is a pity that I have to declare the lambda multiple times for each interface type. But atleast it works. Thanks.

Comment: You have to declare one for each interface pointer anyway. Recall that you spell out the pointer in the lambda capture list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to write inline functions instead of lambdas so that I could take advantage of function overloading (right-term?). The actual is is based on the comments provided.

### Getting Value

```cpp
#pragma warning(suppress: 26415 26417 26429 26460)
inline void GetProperty(HRESULT(__stdcall MSAToolsLibrary::ICongregation::* method)(BSTR*), MSAToolsLibrary::ICongregationPtr& pCongregation, CString &rStrText)
{
    BSTR str{};
    THROW_IF_FAIL((pCongregation->*method)(&str));
    rStrText = CString(str);
};
```

### Setting Value

```cpp
#pragma warning(suppress: 26415 26417 26429 26460)
inline void SetProperty(HRESULT(__stdcall MSAToolsLibrary::ICongregation::* method)(BSTR), MSAToolsLibrary::ICongregationPtr& pCongregation, const CString& rStrText)
{
    THROW_IF_FAIL((pCongregation->*method)(rStrText.AllocSysString()));
};
```